# Выдвижное меню в приложении Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, java

Недавно начал изучать программирование под Android и задался вопросом. Почти в каждом приложении есть выдвижное меню слева, чтобы сдедать его нужно создать новую активность или просто добавить элемент LinearLayout?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте дефолтный NavigationDrawer который предлагает гугл

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы имеете ввиду SlidingMenu. Для этого можно использовать стороннюю библиотеку, например, [эту](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/slidingmenu). Новое активити в таком случае не нужно, там можно просто установить отдельный layout для меню.

Comment: Таак, хорошо. Скачал я библиотеку, импортировал папку library в Eclipse. Теперь необходимо связать библиотеку с моим проектом. Зашёл в Properties моего проекта, и добавил (Add) library. Никаких изменений в проекте я не увидел. Что делать?

Comment: Очевидно, что надо искать SlidingMenu android example. Все достаточно просто, но с первого взгляда не совсем очевидно. Если в двух словах, то вам необходимо создать разметку для меню и экземпляр класса SlidingMenu в коде, после этого все должно работать.

Comment: @murash, там в инструкции есть пункт "How to Integrate this Library into Your Projects". Я бы сделал extends SlidingActivity и указал бы layout меню с помощью метода setBehindContentView().